# How to allow only some characters in sql (oracle)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just looked now for hours how to allow only the characters w,p,s,v in my column. I wrote it like that but there is only every time a fail.

```
ALTER TABLE Personal ADD 
CONSTRAINT Typ
CHECK (Typ like '%^[w,p,s,v]%');

ALTER TABLE Personal
DROP CONSTRAINT CHK_Typ;
```

I really need this help :(

Comment: is w,p,s,v a continuous occurrence or can they occur anywhere in that ?

Comment: Would be helpful to see your INSERT statement and the error code.

Comment: also datatype and size of column Typ would be helpful

Comment: CREATE TABLE PERSONAL(
PERSID INT PRIMARY KEY,
NACHNAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
VORNAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
TELEFONNUMMER INT NOT NULL,
EMAIL VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
RAUM VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
TYP VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL);

Comment: Fehler beim Start in Zeile: 117 in Befehl -
ALTER TABLE Personal ADD 
CONSTRAINT Typ
CHECK (Typ like '%^[w,p,s,v]%')
Fehlerbericht -
ORA-02293: (INF529.TYP)kann nicht validiert werden  - Check-Constraint verletzt
02293. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - check constraint violated"
*Cause:    an alter table operation tried to validate a check constraint to
           populated table that had nocomplying values.
*Action:   Obvious

Comment: it should occur only one of this characters after that i need to update it . and after that i need to cancel it with delete or smth

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47875599/edit) to include all of that information, and format it properly. It does belong in comments.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
alter table personal add constraint ch_typ check (translate(typ, '.wpsv', '.') is null);
```

Comment: ORA-02293: (INF529.CH_TYP) kann nicht validiert werden - Check-Constraint verletzt
02293. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - check constraint violated"
*Cause:    an alter table operation tried to validate a check constraint to
           populated table that had nocomplying values.
*Action:   Obvious

Comment: @zazaza - the error explanation is crystal-clear, do you have difficulty understanding it? You are trying to enforce a constraint that is **already** violated by existing values in that column.

Comment: It means that data that already exist in the table violate the newly added constraint. Make it ENABLE NOVALIDATE.